# How to make a query with the filter in a generic list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, ef-core-2.1

I have the generic object `T`.

I want to do query informing the properties just like I do in SQL with the logical operator or `"OR column1 = 123"` or `"OR column2 = 123"`

```
public ActionResult Result<T>(HttpContext httpContext, IQueryable<T> queryable, string[] columns = null)
{
    var entity = queryable;
    string searchValue = "123";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
    {
        entity = entity.Where(""); // columns              
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use generics if you are trying to access properties of a _specific_ type (its obviously not generic when you need to access specific things).  Make your parameter be of that type and ditch generics all together, or if you must use generics, make sure you restrict on that type using `where T: someType`.  Unless I am misunderstanding

Comment: @JesusPocoata, Yes. How to make this dynamic ?

Answer (score 1):

You could apply an interface constraint but honestly I would just as soon not do that if I were you because it *could* lead to code that is more difficult to read and maintain.

```
public interface ICommonEntity
{
    string Column1 { get; }
    string Column2 { get; }
}
```

Make any applicable type implement the above interface

```
public ActionResult Result<T>(HttpContext httpContext, IQueryable<T> queryable, string[] columns = null) where T : class, ICommonEntity
{
    var entity = queryable;
    string searchValue = "123";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
    {
        entity = entity.Where(_ => _.Column1 == searchValue || _.Column2 == searchValue);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have entities

```
class Foo {
    public string BazFoo { get; set; }
}

class Bar {
    public string BazBar { get; set; }
}
```

You can create an Interface:

```
public interface IBaz
{
    string GetBaz();
}
```

And implement it by your entities:

```
class Foo : IBaz
{
    public string BazFoo { get; set; }
    public string GetBaz() => BazFoo;
}

class Bar : IBaz
{
    public string BazBar { get; set; }
    public string GetBaz() => BazBar;
}
```

And you can use it in a following way:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
{
    entity = queryable.Where(_ => _.GetBaz() == searchValue);
    ...
}
```